# docker-compose file: How to run service A and tell service B that A is already running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I'm new to deployment world and having this issue when I try to deploy an app. The application I tried to deploy is consists of 2 services. First service is an AI model and the second one is the web app. In order to run the web app, the AI model is has to run first. This is the `docker-compose.yml` that I tried to make:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
        max-image-caption-generator:
                image: quay.io/codait/max-image-caption-generator
                ports:
                        - "5000"
        app:
                build: .
                depends_on:
                        - max-image-caption-generator
                ports:
                        - "8088"
```

Here are my questions:

1. Am I defining the `docker-compose.yml` right?
2. How do I tell `app` to run `the max-image-caption-generator` first?

I was able to build from the file above, I could curl the `http://localhost:5000` and it gave me the right html of the AI model, but I couldn't curl `http://localhost:8088`. It's either connection was reset by peer or it can't connect to the `http://localhost:5000` which means the AI model is not running.

Comment: Looks ok and you are already defining a "depends_on" condition that satisfies #2.  Please post the dockerfile that you are using to build app, my guess is your ports may be wrong.  8088 is a weird port, typically http traffic is on 80 and 8080.

Answer (score 2):

Here is couple misunderstandings in your question:

1. `depends_on` means that `app` will be run after `max-image-caption-generator`, but! Docker will not check if service inside `max-image-caption-generator` properly started or not. You have to add `healthcheck` to be sure that `max-image-caption-generator` is running properly, and after that add condition `service_healthy` to `app`.
2. > or it can't connect to the `http://localhost:5000`

   and **it can't**. Because `localhost:5000` only accessible from **Docker host** but not from container's inside. You have to use container name to be able communicate between containers.

Your docker compose should be like:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  max-image-caption-generator:
    image: quay.io/codait/max-image-caption-generator
    ports:
      - "5000"
    # networks is optional parameter
    networks:
      service_network:
        aliases:
          - generator.hostname
    # use it if you want to start app after max-image-caption-generator will be ready get requests
    # healthcheck:
    #   test: ["CMD", "some_test_script", "--params"]
    #   interval: 30s
    #   timeout: 10s
    #   retries: 2

  app:
    build: .
    # networks is optional parameter
    networks:
      - service_network
    depends_on:
      max-image-caption-generator:
        # set this condition if you added healthcheck to max-image-caption-generator container
        # condition: service_healthy
        # this condition just run app after max-image-caption-generator, and no matter is max-image-caption-generator running properly or not
        condition: service_started
    ports:
      - "8088"

# optional block that may be deleted (docker will use default network)
networks:
  service_network:
    name: service_network
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.10.240/28
          gateway: 10.0.10.241
```

After that you will be able to connect to `max-image-caption-generator` container **from `app` container** using `http://generator.hostname:5000` url (if `networks` block is not provided service may be accessed by `http://max-image-caption-generator:5000` (same as service key))

＊[Here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck) you can find information how healthcheck works.

Comment: You added several unnecessary `networks:` blocks, and you can delete them all.  Compose provides a network named `default` for you and makes each container visible by its Compose service name, so between containers _e.g._ `http://max-image-caption-generator:5000` will be reachable with no special setup.

Comment: @DavidMaze I trying to follow python philosophy and one of rules is `Explicit is better than implicit`. `networks` is not `unnecessary` but `optional`. (anyway I added comments that `networks` is optional)